# Сделать GridView и Splitter на всю высоту

Tags: devexpress

Добавил `settings.Height = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);` но не работает, то есть не отображается на всю высоту а по ширине работает `settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);`

Comment: Нашел решение для Splitter: settings.FullscreenMode = true; надо теперь для GridView найти

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение для Splitter: settings.FullscreenMode = true;